# How to change the row to cloumn in php with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Good Morning ,I find many example but still cannot display i want output,PLS Help Me and Thank
.Now output like this:[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHibI.png)
.I want output like this :[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twTEA.png)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";$username = 'root';$password = "";$database = "ocall";
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);$query = "SELECT * FROM timetable";

echo '<table border="1" ><tr><td><b> <font face="Arial">Day</font></td><td><b><font face="Arial">Date</font></td></tr>';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {$field1name = $row["Day"];$field2name = $row["Date"];

echo '
<tr><td>'.$field1name.'</td><td>'.$field2name.'</td></tr>';}$result->free();}
?>
```

Comment: since you want it horizontally (column wise), you need to format the array first (since your origin is row based), from the loop that you have right now, create two containers (days and dates), loop and push inside there first, then after its done, loop it by `<td>`s

Comment: @Ghost How to format the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way can be by storing values in separate arrays. Please try the following code.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = 'root';
$password = "";
$database = "ocall";
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);
if(!$conn){echo "Error";}
$query = "SELECT * FROM `timetable`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $daytime[] =  $row['Day'] ;
    $dates[] = $row['Date'];
}
echo '<table border=1><tr><td>Day</td>';
foreach($daytime as $d)
{echo '<td>'.$d.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr><tr><td>Dates</td>';
foreach($dates as $d)
{echo '<td>'.$d.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>'
?>
```

Hope this works for you.